# How to run webstorm angularJS application standalone in chrome?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have an angular application on my local machine, I can open my SPA from webstorm over chrome, firefox or IE, but if I try to open the same html file from my windows explorer without using the IDE, it only opens and runs in firefox but nothing on chrome and IE just a blank page. I remember reading that firefox has an internal server or some sort, and chrome doesn't, I don't remember where I read that, if any body knows why please help.

Answer (score 2):

Long term, you are best off running a local fileserver IMO.  You can check out python's simple server example http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm, or I typically run something like this in node:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('./', express.static(__dirname + './'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    return res.redirect('./');
});

// Create a server
var server = app.listen(3513, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on', 3512)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is pure angular you are using, you don't need a server, however you might be running into some security problems, try running without security and see what happens.

For OSX, open Terminal and run:

`$ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`

For Linux run:

`$ google-chrome --disable-web-security`

Also if you're trying to access local files for dev purposes like AJAX or JSON, you can use this flag too.

`-–allow-file-access-from-files`

For Windows go into the command prompt and go into the folder where Chrome.exe is and type

`chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

That should disable the same origin policy and allow you to access local files.

Otherwise taking a look at the console is the most sane thing to do, sometimes error information will pop-up there.

Comment: I have a CORS Plugin on google chrome to take care of the same origin policy, the same page works if I open it from Webstorm and no errors in the console.

Comment: Cannot find much info on which way webstorm bootstraps angular, so I believe the best option is try to run your project as if it was created without webstorm, make sure you have installed node and bower, re-install components (make sure package.json and bower.json files exist), run everything from command line, see what pops up.